# Communication between views with dependency property

Tags: c#, .net, silverlight, mvvm

I'm relatively new in programmation and i can't find the solution of my problem after hours and hours of research. I'm on a silverlight application and i want to communicate between two code behind views.

I have two different views displayed in one, each one of this view have a view model and of course the code behind, and in one of this view i have a button and when i click on this button i want to start a method on the second code behind, in order to affect the display.

To solve my problem and after some research, i have think that i should use dependency property, so here is what i did :

On the first code behind my view i have registered a dependency property with a method if the property change :

```
//i registered here my property, in the code behind my view "P_Recherche"

public static readonly DependencyProperty BoolClickDemandeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("Customer", typeof(bool), 
    typeof(P_Recherche), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnCustomerChangedCallBack));

public bool Customer
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(BoolClickDemandeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(BoolClickDemandeProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnCustomerChangedCallBack(
        DependencyObject sender, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    P_Recherche c = sender as P_Recherche;
    if (c != null)
    {
        c.OnCustomerChanged();
    }
}

//Here is the method/code that i want to start after a "call" (in reality after an update of my boolean) of my other view

protected virtual void OnCustomerChanged()
{
    bool testDemande = viewModel.ClickDemande();
    if (testDemande)
    {
        this.posts.DataContext = new vm_Demande();

        MinimizeDemandeCall();
        MinimizeFamilleCall();
        MaximizePostCall();
    }
}
```

and on the second view, in the code behind, i have declared a property for my dependency property like this :

```
public bool Customer
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(P_Recherche.BoolClickDemandeProperty); }
    set { SetValue(P_Recherche.BoolClickDemandeProperty, value); }
}
```

And i use it for example in a button click event, where i change the value of the property in order to start my method that i declared when i have registered my dependency property :

```
private void BtNewDemande_OnMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
        Customer = true;
}
```

When i click on this button i have an exeption like "dependency property cannot be set on an object of type" (i'm sorry my VS2013 is not in english) so i think i miss something... but i can't find any solution to my problem after all this time that i have spent... thanks a lot for your help ! and i apologize for the bad english :)

Comment: you can achieve the same if you apply MVVM properly in your application. Any reason why you are not using commands to handle the click event in your viewmodel? You can use message service to notify other viewmodels about events.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i was hopeless since yesterday, the most easy way and after i tried it works really good will be to use the messenger (i have MVVM Light), but my boss want to remove the messenger from the application so i try to find a new solution.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you use a completely different approach and refrain from abusing DP-PropertyChanged mechanisms to propagate a button click.

Let's step back and think about what happens: a user clicks somewhere. This happens at a point in time. As far as I can tell from your post, this does not change any data, it does not change the state that is relevant for your domain logic, it merely changes how big parts of your UI are displayed. Like clicking an *expand* button somewhere or opening the dropdown of a ComboBox.

So this is inter-view communication, therefore I would not propagate it into the viewmodel either.

I would just use a plain old event here.
Let me show you:

```
public class InnerViewWithButton : UserControl
{
    public InnerViewWithButton()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        InnerButton.Click+=(sender,args)=>RaiseInnerButtonClicked();
    }
    public event EventHandler InnerButtonClicked;
    private void RaiseInnerButtonClicked()
    {
        var clickHandlers = InnerButtonClicked;
        if (clickHandlers != null) clickHandlers(this, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

public class InnerViewWithMethod : UserControl
{
    ...ctor...
    public void DoSomeMagic()
    {
        ...
    }
}
public class OuterView : UserControl
{
    public OuterView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        MyInnerViewWithButton.InnerButtonClicked +=
            (sender,args) => MyInnerViewWithMethod.DoSomeMagic();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic purpose of having ViewModels is so that they can be easily tested. Your situation calls for two cooperating viewmodels. There's a master and a child viewmodel. When the Customer changes on the master, the child needs to respond. Since MVVM Light is out of the question, you will need to register the child view model with the master view model. The example here is via INotifyPropertyChanged

```
public class MasterViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private Customer _customer;

    public Customer Customer 
    { 
        get { return _customer; }

        set { _customer = value; RaisePropertyChanged("Customer"); }
    }

    private void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName) 
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null) 
        {
           PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArg(propertyName);
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
}

public class ChildViewModel : IDisposable
{
    public ChildViewModel(MasterViewModel masterViewModel)
    {
        _masterViewModel = masterViewModel;
        _masterViewModel.PropertyChanged += OnPropertyChanged;
    }

    public void Dispose() 
    {
        _masterViewModel.PropertyChanged -= OnPropertyChanged;
        _masterViewModel = null;
    }

    private void OnCustomerChanged() 
    {

        MinimizeDemandeCall();
        MinimizeFamilleCall();
        MaximizePostCall();

    }

    public void OnPropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
       if (e.PropertyName == "Customer") OnCustomerChanged();
    }
}
```

Now you can write tests:

```
[TestCase]
public class GivenCustomerChanged_ThenMaximizePostCall
{
    [Test]
    public void Test() 
    {
         var masterViewModel = new MasterViewModel();
         using (var childViewModel = new ChildViewModel(masterViewModel))
         {
              masterViewModel.Customer = new Customer();
         }

         // assert that MaximizePostCall was called
    }
}
```